# How to generate API with swagger-codegen with a different controller name for Java?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

swagger-codegen generates APIControllers based on pathname.

Let's say you have these paths on your swagger.yaml:

/pet/findByStatus:
 /user/{userId}
 /store/inventory

Then codegen is going to generate PetAPIController, UserAPIController, StoreApiController.

But my API is something like:

/private/pet/findByStatus:
 /private/user/{userId}
 /public/store/inventory

so I end up with two main controllers: PrivateAPI and PublicAPI

Is there any way to avoid this? Using tags, or just with the second path word.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Swagger Codegen's `spring` generator has the `useTags` option (true/false) that tells the codegen to use tags to name the interface and controller classes. When using the Swagger Codegen Maven plugin, you can specify this option in the `<configOptions>` section:

```xml
<configuration>
    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
    <language>spring</language>
    <configOptions>
       <useTags>true</useTags>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

When `useTags`=`true`, operations with a specific tag, say `admin`, will be placed into *AdminApi.java* and *AdminApiController.java*.

Make sure to tag all operations in your API definition appropriately:

```yaml
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      tags:    # <-----
        - admin
      ...
```